# Visual Studio 2012 Web Deploy with copyAllUsers=false

Tags: web, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I'm busy trying out the new Web Deploy 3 using Visual Studio 2012.  It's great btw, but I would just like to know how to exclude the user Create/Drop from the database update settings.  If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2012 dbdacfx database provider is used to sync SQL databases and that does not have an option to skip users. To skip users you can use msdeploy directly. This must be installed under C:\program files\iis\Microsoft web deploy V3". Use msdeloy.exe from the command line and use the dbdacfx provider as follows

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:dbfullsql="<connectionstring>" 
-dest:dbfullsql="<destinationconnectionstring>",copyallusers=false
```